# Multiple layers on Google Maps possible

Tags: google-maps-api-3

An advance bail - please excuse me if this is something that is not possible

I have multiple KML files from different sources - one providing the weather data, one providing the traffic data and so on.

Can I add multiple layer with different KML files? If not , how do I put all the info into one map?

Comment: It's possible, see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport (Size and Complexity Restrictions for KML Rendering in Google Maps)

Comment: Thank you ...but a small follow up - if I add 2 -3 layers, the visual display will be the last one or will it be transparent and all can be seen at once - any example in the net ?

Comment: The visual display(the order) basically will depent on the time when the status of the layer changes(the loading of the layers will run asynchronously, large KML takes more time to parse , also cached layers will load faster). You may control the order by using the `zIndex`-property of the layer. The transparency will depent on the features and the applied styles. When you e.g. have a semi-transparent polygons in 1 layer, features of other layers will shine trough. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NCrJ7/

Comment: Assume that I give 4 KML files and one of them is bigger and lets assume no cache. As far as user is concerned, the base maps will be loaded and then asynchronously the layers will be loaded. So the smaller KML will be loaded sooner and bigger ones will be loaded later ifI dont give zIndex. And also where can I get some sample KML files (bigger ones) ?